# how to code disabled input toggle with radiobuttons in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

angular js ques: I have two radio buttons and two respective 
inputs,so  i want disabled toggling for this two radio 
and respective inputs in  ng-repeat??

```
<spanng-repeat="x in names">
<input type="radio"> <input type="text">
<br>
<input type="radio"><input type="text">
</span>
```

Comment: use `ng-disabled` and modify scope model variable you assign it to. Question is very vague, provide more details

Comment: que is not clear do you want to disable input on the change of radio button ?

Comment: Yes I want to disable input on the change of radio button .

Answer (score 0):

try it with [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)

```
<span ng-repeat="x in names">
    <input type="radio" ng-disabled="x === 'name 1'"><input type="text">
    <br>
    <input type="radio" ng-disabled="x === 'name 2'"><input type="text">
</span>
```